# jquery this.attr("action") submits form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume a form with id "serialform" in an html page.

The following JavaScript works as expected.

```
$( "#serialform" ).submit(function( event ) { 
    var action = $( "#serialform" ).attr("action");
    var serial = $("#serial").val()
     ...
     return event.preventDefault();
});
```

However, if I replace the first line of the function to use "this":

```
$( "#serialform" ).submit(function( event ) { 
    var action = this.attr("action");
    var serial = $("#serial").val()
    ...
    return event.preventDefault();
});
```

Then the form submits instead of simply returning the action attribute.  `this` refers to the form element (according to firebug).

I would have thought that `this` would be equivalent to `$( "#serialform" )`.  In any event, I want to get the action attribute of the form that is being submitted.

I'm using jQuery 2.0.3.

Comment: replace `this.attr` with `$(this).attr`

Comment: Try changing `this` to `$(this)`.

Comment: Because you get the error "TypeError: undefined is not a function" or something like that. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). And please read the jQuery tutorial (http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/). It explains what happens inside an event handler and what `this` refers to.

Comment: Avoid issues like this by moving `event.preventDefault();` to the first line of your event handler. By doing so it would have not submitted the form, and instead, shown an error in your console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the DOM node, not the wrapped jQuery node. This DOM node doesn't implement the `.attr` method, so it throws an error.

You need to wrap the DOM node in a jQuery object before you call a jQuery method, like so: `$(this).attr('action')`.

Answer (score 3):

It submits because `this.attr` raises an error (something like "Object whatever has no method 'attr'), then further code doesn't run and the default behavior is not prevented. Check your console.

Inside a jQuery event handler, `this` is the DOM element that triggered the event (the form, in this case). It's not a jQuery object, so it doesn't have an `attr` method.